# Im trying to code a Discomfort Index program in C but im stuck

Tags: c

I've built the main part of the program but the task requires us to add a feature in which if the index is above the "No discomfort" zone, the program returns the decrease in temperature required for the index to be at "No discomfort" (considering humidity is consistent).
The problem im facing is I set a variable named x which i want to represent the decrease in temperature needed but when i try to form a equation to solve for x it only prints 0.Im pretty sure i cant give an equation to the compiler to solve but is there any way i can get the decrease needed printed?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

float main()
{
    float T, RH, x, y;
    printf("Insert current temperature in Celsius: \n");
    scanf("%f", &T);
    printf("Insert current humidity percentage: \n");
    scanf("%f", &RH);
    float DI = T - 0.55 * (1 - 0.01 * RH) * (T - 14.5);
    if  (DI < 21)
         printf("No discomfort");
    else if (DI >= 21 && DI < 24)
         printf("Under 50 percent population feels discomfort");
    else if (DI >= 24 && DI < 27)
        printf("Most 50 percent population feels discomfort");
    else if (DI >= 27 && DI < 29)
        printf("Most of population suffers discomfort");
    else if (DI >= 29 && DI < 32)
        printf("Everyone feels severe stress");
    else if (DI >= 32)
        printf("State of medical emergency");

    if (DI >= 21)
        DI=21;
    x=(DI - 14.5 * 0.55(1 - 0.01 * RH))/(1 - 0.55(1 - 0.01*RH));
    printf("\nThe temperature should be decreased to %.2f degrees\n", x);
    return 0;
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is the problem with the code you show? Please [edit] your question to tell us how it doesn't work as expected. But first please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please post your exact code, it's pointless to look for issues if the code doesn't even compile.

Comment: @Yunnosch I am not sure I understand what you are talking about but I must note this is in C language and I am new to the whole programming experience so I kindly ask you to be as explanatory as possible.

Comment: @Groo this is my code theres nothing else to it

Comment: @EvangelosNikolopoulos: this code [does not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/P59e1o), so it's unlikely that "it only prints 0".

Comment: I changed the indenation of your code to be consistent and to match how C language (in contrast to python) logical structure  works. My changes do not affect functionality. I ask whether this helps you to see the problem of your code, which in my opinion was hidden by the wrong indentation. I still think that the problem is like that, though you first will have to work on the problem described in the answer by John, e.g. by providing a [mre] which demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler is already telling you what's wrong here:

```
x=(DI - 14.5 * 0.55(1 - 0.01 * RH))/(1 - 0.55(1 - 0.01*RH));
```

Something like this:

> error: called object type 'double' is not a function or function pointer

That's because `0.55(1)` is math, not C.  You need a `*`.

Always enable and inspect your compiler warnings before wondering why your code doesn't work.

Comment: You should enable the settings in your compiler so that it does not compile broken code.  For example in GCC or Clang you can add the command line options `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` to catch lots of bugs.

Comment: You clearly are aware that the shown code is not the code exhibiting the problem described by OP. I trust that you will not mind if OP clarifies to a decent MRE and thereby (strictly speaking) creates a moving target qustion away from your answer.